# Memory in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, memory, heap-memory

I'm getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception in Eclipse. I know that Eclipse
by default uses heap size of 256M. I'm trying to increase it but nothing happens.

For example:
eclipse -vmargs -Xmx16g -XX:PermSize=2g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g

I also tried different settings, using only the -Xmx option, using different cases
of g, G, m, M, different memory sizes, but nothing helps. Tried also to specify the values in the eclipse.ini file. Does not matter which params I specify, the heap exception is thrown at the same time, so I assume there's something I'm doing wrong that Eclipse ignores the -Xmx parameter. I'm using a 32GB RAM machine and trying to execute something very simple such as:

double[][] a = new double[15000][15000];

It only works when I reduce the array size to something around 10000 on 10000.

I'm working on Linux and using the top command I can see how much memory the Java
process is consuming; it's less than 2%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a solution after reading 
[Why does heap space run out only when running JUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681133/eclipse-outofmemoryerror-heap-space)

When I specify the -Xmx inside eclipse by going to run->configuration->vm arguments
and set the -Xmx there, everything works fine :)