# SPARQL query take a longer time in Eclipse compare to commande line

Tags: java, eclipse, rdf, sparql, jena

I need to compare SPARQL to SQL(Oracle based).
So I started with Jena and Eclipse. I created my RDF file and queries in SPARQL but when I execute a query in command line it took 5 secondes to get the result and with Eclipse it took 15 secondes !
The difference between the two computation times is huge  and I can't compare properly these databases...

Is anyone know why ?

I save my RDF file in RDF/XML mode (by default).

Thanks !

There's the code i use :

```
String q = "SELECT ?appID ?appLibelle ?droit ?login ?password ?prenom ?nom "
            + "WHERE { "
            + "?empdroitapp EMPDROITAPP:EMP_ID ?emp . "
            + "?empdroitapp EMPDROITAPP:APP_ID ?app . "
            + "?empdroitapp EMPDROITAPP:EMPDroitAPP_Droit ?droit . "
            + "OPTIONAL { ?empapp EMPAPP:EMP_ID ?emp . "
            + "?empapp EMPAPP:APP_ID ?app . "
            + "?empapp EMPAPP:EMPAPP_Login ?login . "
            + "?empapp EMPAPP:EMPAPP_Password ?password . } . "
            + "?emp EMP:EMP_ID ?empID . "
            + "?emp EMP:EMP_Prenom ?prenom . "
            + "?emp EMP:EMP_Nom ?nom . "
            + "?app APP:APP_ID ?appID . "
            + "?app APP:APP_Libelle ?appLibelle . "
            + "} ORDER BY ASC(?empID)";

    String prefix = "PREFIX LDAP:      <http://example.com/property#>";
    String prefixEMP = "PREFIX EMP:      <http://example.com/property/emp#>";
    String prefixAPP = "PREFIX APP:      <http://example.com/property/app#>";
    String prefixEMPAPP = "PREFIX EMPAPP:      <http://example.com/property/empapp#>";
    String prefixEMPDROITAPP = "PREFIX EMPDROITAPP:      <http://example.com/property/empdroitapp#>";
    String queryString = prefix + NL + prefixEMP + NL + prefixAPP + NL
            + prefixEMPAPP + NL + prefixEMPDROITAPP + q;

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    //query.serialize(new IndentedWriter(System.out, false));
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m);
    long chrono = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        // Assumption: it's a SELECT query.
        ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();

        //String str = "appID\tappLibelle\tdroit\tlogin\tpassword\tprenom\tnom\n";
        // The order of results is undefined.
        for (; rs.hasNext();) {
            QuerySolution rb = rs.nextSolution();

            // Get title - variable names do not include the '?' (or '$')
            RDFNode appID = rb.get("appID");
            RDFNode appLibelle = rb.get("appLibelle");
            RDFNode droit = rb.get("droit");
            RDFNode login = rb.get("login");
            RDFNode password = rb.get("password");
            RDFNode prenom = rb.get("prenom");
            RDFNode nom = rb.get("nom");

            // Check the type of the result value

            if (appID.isResource()) {
                Resource res = (Resource) appID;
                System.out.print("\t" + res);
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t" + appID);
            }

            if (appLibelle != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + appLibelle);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");

            if (droit != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + droit);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");

            if (login != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + login);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");

            if (password != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + password);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");

            if (prenom != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + prenom);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");

            if (nom != null) {
                System.out.print("\t" + nom);
            } else System.out.print("\tnull");
            System.out.println();
            //str += "\n";
        }
        //System.out.println(str);
    } finally {
        // QueryExecution objects should be closed to free any system
        // resources
        qexec.close();
    }
    long tmp = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Temps écoulé : " + (tmp - chrono) + "ms");
```

Comment: There is nothing _obviously_ wrong in your code, but of course runtime performance depends not just on your code, but also on the size and shape of your data, how you add that data to your store/model, the amount of available memory to your JRE, to name but a few factors. In other words, this is a bit too broad to be answerable in its current form.

Comment: As a general point I would also say that if you are comparing SPARQL and SQL, my personal opinion is that you should not really be looking at the performance of one particular SPARQL implementation (Jena) vs one particular SQL implementation (Oracle), but rather focus on expressivity, fitness for purpose, etc.

Comment: That's the same data file and queries I run first on Eclipse and via command line on another hand. This is also the same computer that run everything. 
I add the data with Jena, if you want I can edit my first post to put it in.
My JRE memory doesn't change between Eclipse and shell.

To answer to your second post, I have to compare SPARQL using jena with a single relational database so I choose Oracle.. It's not all of my choice

Comment: Ah, sorry, the question is explicitly about the performance difference between running from Eclipse and shell - I didn't get that, I thought you were generally asking why the query was slow. 

I would doublecheck that your JRE memory is the same in both instances - it seems the most likely difference. Best way to guarantee identical memory conditions is to explicitly run your program with a `-Xmx` flag with enough memory.

Comment: One more general comment: databases in general often need to "warm up" their indices before they become performant. Doing a single run of a query is likely to give skewed results. Try running the query ten times in a row (with a simple `for`-loop or something) and averaging the response times.

Comment: So I tried to run Eclipse with 8 and 12G memory but it still take 15 or 16 secondes.. When I check running processus I can see a new one after I run my program. If it's a warm up problems so why in command line it only took 5 or 6 seconds for one query ? (5 or 6 with the database close before)

Comment: Running Eclipse is not the same as running your own code in Eclipse. Make sure you are configuring your own program to use enough RAM. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570273/memory-in-eclipse

Comment: I edit my run configuration to change that but it take still the same times (sometimes more)

I'm on MAC OSX (MBP 2014)