# I'm getting a Out Of Memory Error: Java heap space Exception

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am currently trying to take in a text file and read each word in the file into a binary tree the specific error i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

the text file i am reading into the project was given to me by the professor for the assignment so i know this should not be running into any memory problems i have never felt with this type of exception before and don't know where to start please help. here is my code:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Tester run = new Tester();
        run.it();
    }

    public void it() throws FileNotFoundException { 
        BTree theTree = new BTree();
        String str = this.readInFile();
        String [] firstWords = this.breakIntoWords(str);
        String [] finalWords = this.removeNullValues(firstWords);

        for(int i = 0; i < finalWords.length; i++) {
            theTree.add(finalWords[i]);
        }
        theTree.print();
    }

    public String readInFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String myFile = "";
        int numWords = 0;
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(new File("Dracula.txt"));

        while(myScan.hasNext() == true) {
            myFile += myScan.nextLine() + " ";
        }
        return myFile;
    }

    public String [] breakIntoWords(String myFile) {
        String[] words = new String[myFile.length()];
        String nextWord = "";
        int position = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while(myFile.length() > position) {
            char next = myFile.charAt(position);
            next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

            // First trim beginning
            while (((next < 'a') || (next > 'z')) && !Character.isDigit(next)) {
                position++;
                next = myFile.charAt(position);
                next = Character.toLowerCase(next);
            }

            // Now pull only letters or numbers until we hit a space
            while(!Character.isWhitespace(next)) {
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(next)) {
                    nextWord += myFile.charAt(position);
                }
                position++; 
                next = myFile.charAt(position);
            }
            words [i] = nextWord;
            i++;
        }
        return words;
    }

    public String[] removeNullValues(String[] myWords) {
        String[] justMyWords = new String[myWords.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < myWords.length; i++) {
            if (myWords[i] != null) {
                justMyWords[i] = myWords[i];
            }
        }
        return justMyWords;
    }
}
```

Here's my B-tree class:

```
public class BTree {
    private BTNode root;
    private int nodeCount;

    public boolean add(String word) {
        BTNode myNode = new BTNode(word);

        if(root == null) {
            root = myNode;
            nodeCount++;
            return true;
        }

        if(findNode(word)) {
            int tmp = myNode.getNumInstance();
            tmp++;
            myNode.setNumInstance(tmp);
            return false;
        }

        BTNode temp = root;
        while(temp != null) {
            if(word.compareTo(temp.getMyWord()) < 0) {
                if(temp.getRightChild() == null) {
                    temp.setLeftChild(myNode);
                    nodeCount++;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    temp = temp.getRightChild();
                }
            } else {
                if(temp.getLeftChild() == null) {
                    temp.setLeftChild(myNode);
                    nodeCount++;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    temp = temp.getLeftChild();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean findNode(String word) {
        return mySearch(root, word);
    }

    private boolean mySearch(BTNode root, String word) {
        if (root == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((root.getMyWord().compareTo(word) < 0)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (word.compareTo(root.getMyWord()) > 0) {
                return mySearch(root.getLeftChild(), word);
            } else {
                return mySearch(root.getRightChild(), word);
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        printTree(root);
    }

    private void printTree(BTNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.print(".");
            return;
        }
        printTree(root.getLeftChild());
        System.out.print(root.getMyWord());
        printTree(root.getRightChild());

    }

    public int wordCount() {
        return nodeCount;
    }
}
```

And my B-tree node class:

```
public class BTNode {
    private BTNode rightChild;
    private BTNode leftChild;
    private String myWord;
    private int numWords;
    private int numInstance;
    private boolean uniqueWord;
    private boolean isRoot;
    private boolean isDeepest;

    public BTNode(String myWord){

        this.numInstance = 1;
        this.myWord = myWord;
        this.rightChild = null;
        this.leftChild = null;

    }

    public String getMyWord() {
        return myWord;
    }

    public void setMyWord(String myWord) {
        this.myWord = myWord;
    }

    public BTNode getRightChild() {
        return rightChild;
    }

    public void setRightChild(BTNode rightChild) {
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }

    public BTNode getLeftChild() {
        return leftChild;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(BTNode leftChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
    }

    public int getnumWords() {
        return numWords;
    }

    public void setnumWords(int numWords) {
        this.numWords = numWords;
    }

    public boolean isUniqueWord() {
        return uniqueWord;
    }

    public void setUniqueWord(boolean uniqueWord) {
        this.uniqueWord = uniqueWord;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return isRoot;
    }

    public void setRoot(boolean isRoot) {
        this.isRoot = isRoot;
    }

    public boolean isDeepest() {
        return isDeepest;
    }

    public void setDeepest(boolean isDeepest) {
        this.isDeepest = isDeepest;
    }

    public int getNumInstance() {
        return numInstance;
    }

    public void setNumInstance(int numInstance) {
        this.numInstance = numInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is the Dracula.txt file?

Comment: You need to configure the memory using few arguements.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570273/memory-in-eclipse

Comment: Why not process each line as you read it instead of building a really large String and an even larger String[]

Comment: Dracula.txt is 883KB on my computer . . . its just a text file containing the actual book Dracula.

Comment: Add VM arguments :                                                 -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size                            or  run it using : java -Xmx256m yourclass.java

Comment: I would test if your program works for 1/50th of this file for example - you might have an error which creates infinite tree. In Eclipse you can also go to Run > Run configurations... > Select your program, go to "arguments" tab and insert -Xmx1024m in "VM arguments". It sets heap size to 1024 MB, you can also set it to higher value.

Comment: Usually, OutOfMemoryError is a design problem for such small inputs. Could you give us the stacktrace please ?

Comment: BTW your removeNullValue does nothing ;) it copy non null values, and let null values in the array by not copying null values

Comment: When you are building the tree, you are inserting nodes in the wrong side when you should insert the element to the right.After the if(temp.getRightChild() == null) check, you should add the node to the right, not to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little file should not be the reason for the OutOfMemory error.

**Performance**
That is no error, but if you want to read a whole file in the memory
don't read line per line and concatenate the strings. This slows down your programm.
You can use:

```
String myFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Dracula.txt")));
myFile = myFile.replaceAll("\r\n", " ");
return myFile;
```

That is also not superfast, but faster.

**Now the Errors**

**word array is too large**

```
public String[] breakIntoWords(String myFile) {
    String[] words = new String[myFile.length()];
```

You define words as an array of lengh *lenght of file* . That is much too large if you
the name is mnemonic and means that you need an array of length *count of words in file*

**nextWord is never resetted (Cause of OutOfMemory**)

```
        // Now pull only letters or numbers until we hit a space
        while (!Character.isWhitespace(next)) {
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(next)) {
                nextWord += myFile.charAt(position);
            }
            position++;
            next = myFile.charAt(position);
        }
        words[i] = nextWord;
        i++;
```

because next word is never set to "" after assigning it to words[i]. So that next word grow
up word by word and your array contents looks like as:

```
words[0] = "Word1"
words[1] = "Word1Word2"
words[2] = "Word1Word2Word3"
```

As you can imagine, that will result in an very large amount of used space.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building the tree, you are inserting nodes in the wrong side when you should insert the element to the right.

You should replace this code at BTree class:

```
        while(temp != null) {
        if(word.compareTo(temp.getMyWord()) < 0) {
            if(temp.getRightChild() == null) {
                temp.setRightChild(myNode); // <-- You were using setLeftChild()
                nodeCount++;
                return true;
            } else {
                temp = temp.getRightChild();
            }
        ....
    }
```

You are probably creating a huge tree with all the elements to the left side and getting the OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Add VM arguments :

```
-Xms<size> set initial Java heap size 
-Xmx<size> set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size> set java thread stack size
```

or run it using : java -Xmx256m yourclass.java

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factors.

1. Amount of java heap you are running with (default values differ for 32 bit and 64 bit JDK)
2. Size of the file you feed to the java program

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load entire contents of the file(i.e. stream object) into Java Memory. In such case, your file size limited(i.e small) Then above code will work in your limited memory but if the file size is increased(i.e. Contents of the file is increased). Then you will face issue.

You have to follow better approach to solve this problem by reading the file contents in chuck. Otherwise you will face same issue.

If you increase JVM arguments also won't work for larger files.

I feel your professor also testing the implementation of your project.